# No coverage for unit test

Tags: testing, code-coverage

I create a "Basic" app from Android Studio Arctic Fox initial screen. I create SimpleClass and SimpleTest, and the test passes. Then right click the test to run "with coverage". The test passed, Code Coverage says "No coverage for all classes in scope. I have tried Code Coverage runner of Idea and jacoco and both give the same results:
[Test Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d15Vh.png)
`

```
class SimpleClass(p1: String){
    var a: String
    var b: String
    init {
        a = p1
        b = p1
    }
}

class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    fun testA(){
        val simpleClass = SimpleClass("hello world")
        assert(simpleClass.a  =="hello world", )
        assert(simpleClass.b == "hello world")
    }

in Build.gradle:
buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
        this.isTestCoverageEnabled = true
    }
}
```

`
[Test coverage result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S09cH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be several reasons for this problem, but in my case I fixed this way :

- Edit Run/Debug configuration :

  - Modify options
  - [Code Coverage] Specify classes and packages

    - On the new displayed "code coverage" section, click + to add your packages
  - Again click on "Modify options"
  - [Code Coverage] Collect coverage in test folders

Screenshot :
[image: Run/Debug configurations]